# Splash screen aspect ratio distorted in windows surface 3 tablet

Tags: cordova, windows-mobile, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I have a windows app , it is a cordova based application developed in visual studio 2015.
The issue is that the splash screen is distorted for windows surface 3 tablet but is coming in correct aspect ratio for windows 10 desktops and windows 10 laptops. Is there a specific screen resolution which we have to take care of to cover windows surface 3 too?

Comment: Could you share a demo, so that I can test it on my surface device?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT can i send it privately to you?

Comment: Sorry, offering Email for service is against our company's principle.  You can make a very basic demo without any business logic inside. Or post the codes of this demo in your question. But please also make sure it can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT this is the link to demo , please check on surface 3 and let me know , https://www.dropbox.com/s/26usfy2nq4q4e9n/CordovaApp.Windows_1.0.0.0_x64_demo.zip?dl=0  , thanks